# How to check if Date parameter has some value in Java

Tags: java, validation, date

I'm moving from C# to java and I'm having troubles with the basics. I'm expecting a variable in my method of type Date and I need to check if the Date has been set or not. How do I do that in Java? using ,equals or == ??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you want:

```
public void foo(Date date) {
  if (date != null) {
    // Use date here
  }
}
```

Note that unlike `DateTime` in .NET, `java.util.Date` is a class (and therefore a reference type)... Java doesn't have "custom" value types.

Also note that that's not quite the same as whether or not the variable has been "set". For example:

```
Date date = new Date();
date = null;
```

Would you consider that variable to be "set" or not? It's set to have a null reference as its value. I *suspect* you want to know whether the variable has a value referring to an object, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( myDate != null){
 //do your stuff here
}
```